# Why do not read from the realm database in the first run properly

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I have an activity where I store information from the Api and store it in the database
And in the group I read this information from the database
But the problem is that when I run the program for the first time, the information is not read, but when I close the program and re-run it, the information is read correctly.

How can I fix this problem?

**code of save to realm in main activity**

```
                    //save to realm
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentWeatherModel.size(); i++)
                        realm.copyToRealm(currentWeatherModel.get(i));
                    realm.commitTransaction();`
```

**code read from realm in fragment**

```
private void readDatabase() {
    RealmResults<CurrentWeatherModel> results = realm.where(CurrentWeatherModel.class).findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

        String icon = results.get(i).getIcon();
        double temp = results.get(i).getTemp();
        int humidity = results.get(i).getHumidity();
        double speed = results.get(i).getSpeed();
        int all = results.get(i).getAll();
        int id = results.get(i).getId();
        String description = results.get(i).getDescription();

       //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), temp+"a", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```